# my voice cable modem is DOCSIS 2.0, do I need to upgrade. I only use it for voice

Tags: modem, cable, voice

my voice cable modem is DOCSIS 2.0, do I need to upgrade. I only use it for voice. My provider says that they no longer support DOCSIS 2.0.  I have a seperate DOCSIS 3.0 cable modem for my internet.

Comment: I have both kinds of boxes here and both up to date. If the ISP says your older box out of support then you should update to avoid support issues

Comment: *"My provider says that they no longer support DOCSIS 2.0."* - Then you should probably upgrade.

Comment: DOCSIS 2 is ancient and it's not just a versioning or throughput difference - DOCSIS 2 and DOCSIS 3 are completely different in the transmission signal ranges.  [Netgear](https://kb.netgear.com/24802/DOCSIS-2-vs-DOCSIS-3-differences) offers a simple explanation, whereas [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOCSIS) offers a highly technical one.  Synopsis: if the provider of the upstream and downstream transmissions say they don't support DOCSIS 2, best to conform =]

Comment: @Anaksunaman - I agree with your comment.  However, the author should specifically asked their ISP to perform the upgrade, if the DOCSIS 2 hardware, will not longer be supported by the ISP's network.

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP says update your cable modem, you update it. They can suspend your service for non-compliance, so you'd better do it.

Having an old device on their network can cause them multiple problems, so I understand why they want you to upgrade.